# Plotting piecewise continuous functions with WM_TIMER

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to plot some graph step by step via WM_PAINT. As I understand, I should create timer to create delay.

Here's a map of my tries:

```
case WM_CREATE: 
    SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 10000, NULL);
    break;
```

So here I have a neat 10 second timer.

Then I do

```
case WM_TIMER: 
   MessageBeep(-1);
   InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
   break;
```

How I should execute my timer in WM_PAINT? I thought that my timer should always work but i cant hear a beep at all.

Here's my WM_PAINT:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        a = sx / 2;
        b = sy / 2;
        R = 100;
        SelectObject(hdc, blackPen);
        MoveToEx(hdc, 0, b, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, sx, b);
        MoveToEx(hdc, a, 0, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, a, sy);
        MoveToEx(hdc, a, b, NULL);
        SelectObject(hdc, redPen);


        for (x = 0.0; x < 2 * 3, 14; x += 0.1) {
            y = x + exp(2*x);
            LineTo(hdc, x, y);
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: MessageBeep is not an ideal way to debug a program.  Be sure to learn how to set a debugger breakpoint.

Comment: Specifically, a [tracepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints) is a non-intrusive way to find out, whether a particular region of code runs.

Comment: First, please check your computer sound card to see if it plays the sound normally. Second, try to replace `MessageBox(hWnd, L"trigger", L"", MB_OK)` with `MessageBeep(-1)` to see the effect more directly. Third, learning how to [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)  is very good for solving problems.